# How to detect and perform necessary actions when user clears the live activity from the Lock Screen

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios16, swiftui-animation

Looking for a solution to re create the same live activity, if the user clears it from the Lock Screen.

Is there any way, we get some callbacks in code as soon as user clears the live notification from the lock screen.

Or is there anyway we can disable the user to clear the live activity from the Lock Screen.